# XML child node without namespace

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following xml and child node is without prefix.

```
<ns1:SearchResponse xmlns:ns1="alpwsdl.masterPricer" 
                    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
> 
  <SearchReturn xsi:type="ns1:searchReply"> 
    <searchReference xsi:type="xsd:int">1234</searchReference> 
  </SearchReturn> 
</ns1:SearchResponse>
```

In my xml schema the prefix is for child node and parent node.

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns="alpwsdl.masterPricer" 
            targetNamespace="alpwsdl.masterPricer"
            elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:element name="SearchResponse">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="SearchReturn">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="searchReference">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:simpleContent>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I don't understand the question - you either adjust the XML document to match the schema (use a default namespace or add the prefix to the descendant elements) or adjust the schema to match the document (remove the `elementFormDefault`). Which approach is correct depends on so many different factors.

Comment: remove the elementFormDefault was the soultion I searched. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, the problem can be solved by removing the `elementFormDefault` attribute, but in the general case, when you want to use multiple namespaces within the same document, you can split the definition into multiple XSD files.:

schema.xsd:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:ns1="alpwsdl.masterPricer">
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="schema1.xsd" namespace="alpwsdl.masterPricer"/>
    <xsd:element name="SearchReturn">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:all>
                <xsd:element ref="searchReference" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xsd:all>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="searchReference" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

schema1.xsd:

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="alpwsdl.masterPricer" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:ns1="alpwsdl.masterPricer">
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="schema.xsd"/>
    <xsd:element name="SearchResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:all>
                <xsd:element ref="SearchReturn" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xsd:all>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```